# Sum of a series with square root

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-theorem

How to calculate the sum for $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n-i+1} \sqrt{\left( \sum_{r=0}^{i-1} \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}\left( p \right)^r  \left( 1-p \right)^{n-r} \right)}$ when $n$ is finite?
Any suggestion or references will be highly appreciated.